# Extend date class

Tags: python

I have issue with extending `date` class in python.

Since date is static class, however, I haven't get it working as it supposed to be. I tried to modify code base on `datetime`, since this class extend from `date`. However, failed.

Question is:

1. How to modify code to make it working like:

> ed = ExtendDate(2011,1,1,week=3, quarter=3)
>
> print ed.week  # 3

2. How to deal with `__new__`, and `__init__` in python static class (in theory) ?
3. How to extend date class (in general) ?

Thanks.

```
class ExtendDate(date):
    """Extend to have week and quarter property"""

    #
    # def __init__(self, year, month, day, week=None, quarter=None):
    #     pass

    def __init__(self, year, month, day, week=None, quarter=None):
        print 0
        super(ExtendDate, self).__init__(year,month,day)
        print 1
        self._week = week
        self._quarter = quarter


    @staticmethod
    def __new__(cls, year, month, day, week=None, quarter=None):
        cls._week = 1
        super(ExtendDate, cls).__new__(year, month, day)

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        if self.cmp_year(other) in [-1,0,1]:
            return self.cmp_year(other)

        if hasattr(self, 'quarter'):
            return self.cmp_quarter(other)

        if hasattr(self, 'week'):
            return self.cmp_week(other)
        # TODO: test - what if it's just a normal date object ?
        pass

    def cmp_quarter(self, other):
        if self.quarter < other.quarter:
            return -1
        elif self.quarter == other.quarter:
            return 0
        elif self.quarter > other.quarter:
            return 1

    def cmp_week(self, other):
        if self.week < other.week:
            return -1
        elif self.week == other.week:
            return 0
        elif self.week > other.week:
            return 1

    def cmp_year(self, other):
        if self.year < other.year:
            return -1
        elif self.year == other.year:
            return 0
        elif self.year > other.year:
            return 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'year:' + str(self.year) + ' ' + \
              'quarter:' + str(self.quarter) + ' ' + \
              'month:' + str(self.month) + ' '+ \
              'week:' + str(self.week) + ' '+ \
              'day:' + str(self.day) + ' '

    week = property(lambda self: 0)
    quarter = property(lambda self: 0)

    @week.setter
    def week(self, value):
        self._week = value

    @quarter.setter
    def quarter(self, value):
        self._quarter = value
```

Comment: Why would you make a date constructor that takes redundant information such as week and quarter when it also takes Y/M/D?  What if the user calls it with conflicting data?  Wouldn't it be better to simply compute the week and quarter as needed?

Comment: yeah, i want to attach some property to date class in order to cache on the object, rather than compute it in external function. The reason is Encapsulation. I think the concept of 'week' can be placed into date's subtype. @JohnZwinck

Comment: Side-note: Your comparison code is crazy complicated. Even if you don't use modern style Py3 rich comparison functions (admittedly more annoying to use when inheriting from a class that defines them), you could replace the definition of, and calls to various `cmp_*` methods with just `cmp(self.year, other.year)`. If you can force the existence of `quarter` and `week`, it can simplify further to just a single call to `cmp((self.year, self.quarter, self.week), (other.year, other.quarter, other.week))` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__new__` isn't supposed to be decorated with `@staticmethod` (it's a class method implicitly, no decorator should be used). And it's supposed to return the instance created, where your code is modifying `cls` (which it shouldn't) and not returning the result of the `super` `__new__` call (which it should). Also, if you're providing a `__new__` (to make the class logically immutable), you shouldn't provide a `__init__`.

Really, the code you'd want would be something like:

```
class ExtendDate(date):
    """Extend to have week and quarter property"""
    __slots__ = '_week', '_quarter'  # Follow date's lead and limit additional attributes

    def __new__(cls, year, month, day, week=None, quarter=None):
        self = super(ExtendDate, cls).__new__(cls, year, month, day)
        self._week = week
        self._quarter = quarter
        return self
```

Presumably, you'd also want functional getters, e.g.

```
    @property
    def week(self):
        return self._week

    # ... etc. ...
```

Comment: TypeError: datetime.date.__new__(X): X is not a type object (int)

Comment: I copy the idea from datetime, it derive from date class.

Comment: @CodeFarmer: Ah, oops. Copied and pasted from your code. Fixed now. Unlike `__init__`, where `self` is passed implicitly, you must pass `cls` explicitly to the `super` `__new__` call.

Answer (score 0):

As @ShadowRanger answsered, I changed some lines to make it working.

The major change is `__new__(cls, year, month, day)`:

```
from datetime import date


class ExtendDate(date):
    """Extend to have week and quarter property"""
    __slots__ = '_week', '_quarter'


    def __new__(cls, year, month, day, week=None, quarter=None):
        # self = super(ExtendDate, cls).__new__(year, month, day)
        self = date.__new__(cls, year, month, day)
        self._week = week
        self._quarter = quarter
        return self

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        if self.cmp_year(other) in [-1,0,1]:
            return self.cmp_year(other)

        if hasattr(self, 'quarter'):
            return self.cmp_quarter(other)

        if hasattr(self, 'week'):
            return self.cmp_week(other)
        # TODO: test - what if it's just a normal date object ?
        pass

    def cmp_quarter(self, other):
        if self.quarter < other.quarter:
            return -1
        elif self.quarter == other.quarter:
            return 0
        elif self.quarter > other.quarter:
            return 1

    def cmp_week(self, other):
        if self.week < other.week:
            return -1
        elif self.week == other.week:
            return 0
        elif self.week > other.week:
            return 1

    def cmp_year(self, other):
        if self.year < other.year:
            return -1
        elif self.year == other.year:
            return 0
        elif self.year > other.year:
            return 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'year:' + str(self.year) + ' ' + \
              'quarter:' + str(self.quarter) + ' ' + \
              'month:' + str(self.month) + ' '+ \
              'week:' + str(self.week) + ' '+ \
              'day:' + str(self.day) + ' '


    @property
    def week(self):
        return self._week

    @property
    def quarter(self):
        return self._quarter


ed = ExtendDate(2011,1,2,3,4)
print type(ed)
print ed._week
```